# How to run through a list a variables within a loop? - python

Tags: python, loops, variables, tkinter

I am working on a project that solves sudoku puzzles. To gather the inputs I am using a GUI called "Tkinter" with 81 separate input(entry) boxes. I also have a submit button. When I press submit I would like to create a series of objects that contain atribues like cell value, row, and column. the code below does this, but I would have to copy and paste this code 81 times only adjusting the variable names and position by one each time(within the submit function). Is there any way to create a loop that could iterate these lines of code 81 times while altering the number part of the variable names?

```py
class Cell:
    def __init__(self,number,location):
        self.number = number
        self.row = (location // 9) + 1
        self.column = (location % 9) + 1

def submit():
    cell1 = Cell(c1.get(),0)
    cell2 = Cell(c2.get(),1)
    cell3 = Cell(c3.get(),2)
    ...
```

*the .get() method is how I am retrieving the numbers from the input boxes(called c1,c2,c3...) once the button is pressed.

**location is just a number(0-80) that I use to find the row and column info.

Comment: I was going to ask about that too, but it seemed a lot to put in one question. I was hoping the answer to this would help with the problem too.

Comment: @Matiiss there is no need to be rude, "_did you seriously create 81 Entry widgets manually without thinking of a better solution?_" is rude and unneeded. please try to remember we were all beginners at some point and we all needed a friendly hand to help us along.

Comment: @gold_cy well, it wasn't meant to be too rude (tone can't be read in text), more of like, I don't know, amazement or surprise, that someone would repeat their code 81 times without thinking that there must be an easier solution, also I sometimes wonder how people have gotten this far (some knowledge of OOP and other stuff and already building GUIs) but seemingly lack some basics (I still like to help but it kinda amazes me)

Comment: @Matiiss Thank you for your comment. my entry widgets look like ```c1 = Entry(root, width=2, font=("Times",16), justify=CENTER ).grid(row=0, column=0)```. are you saying i can replace the widget name (c1,c2,...) with an item from a list?

Comment: @WillsErda yes (kind of at least), see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest I could think of was to use nested `for` loops to create the widgets and grid them (btw `row` and `column` start at 0) and append to a list, from where they can be later referenced. So when you press the button, it goes over each of the `Entry`s in that list and calls their `get` method (and `print`s the value):

```py
import tkinter as tk


def submit():
    for e in entry_list:
        print(e.get())


root = tk.Tk()

entry_list = []
for col in range(9):
    for row in range(9):
        entry = tk.Entry(root, width=2, font=('Calibri', 20))
        entry.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='news')
        entry_list.append(entry)

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=submit)
btn.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=9)

root.mainloop()
```